# Prepared statement and counting

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysql-num-rows

Anyone has any idea how to count the amount of rows retrieved? It should only be 1 in this case- but I just can't seem to make it work with prepared statements (still very new to using it)

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT playername FROM player_data
                        WHERE playername = ?"))
{   
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["target"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($playername);

    $stmt->fetch();

    $row_cnt = $stmt->num_rows();

    printf("Result set has %s rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    $stmt->close(); 
}
else 
{
    printf("Error: %s", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: first of all, you don't need such a count at all.

Comment: second, if you care to read any of the related questions offered to you, you will easily find an answer

Comment: I tried to look around and I haven't been made to make anything work- and yes, I do need the count? I only want to show things if it finds that one row.

Comment: don't you have a $playername already for this purpose?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course! But if it doesn't find any $playername, I'd like to redirect the user to another page. I just haven't added that yet, seeing as I didn't make the other part work :P

Comment: there is an `else` statement in PHP, directly for this purpose.

Comment: My common sense is being very vague to me! :D Yes. Indeed there is - but how would I add this ELSE if I can't even make it print 1 or 0 depending if there's a playername present or not. :(

Comment: you don't need nor 0 nor 1 if you have a player name itself

Comment: Furk. I'm an idiot. You're right. I know how to make it work it now, thanks!

Comment: BTW, it's worth to call store_result() anyway, just to make mysqli able to call another query (if any)

Comment: I just recently started using prepared statements - how does store_result work?

Comment: Ahhh! I just made num_rows work (even though I don't need it, as you pointed out) because of your indirect help! Thanks you sweetheart!